# How to print order details for event observer sales_order_save_after

Tags: magento2, module, event-observer

want to print order details and product details (variants) which are ordered.

> My xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_save_after">
        <observer name="recipes_sales_order_save_after" 
         instance="Vendorname\Modulename\Observer\Observer" />
    </event>

    </config>
```

> My observer file

```
<?php namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Observer; 
        use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface; 
             public function __construct(
            \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order
        )
        {
            $this->order = $order;
        }
           public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer 
          $observer)
         {
            $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
           $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/nitesh.log');
            $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
            $logger->addWriter($writer);
           $logger->info($order->getOrderId());


         foreach( $order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item ) {

         $logger->info( $item->getHana());  //" HANA is new attribute name"
          $logger->info( $item->getProductId());
         }
```

but getHana not print

[image]

Comment: have you check getQty, getPrice and getHana values in your database?

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load product and then get attribute value using below code. Add that code in your `execute()` function :

```
<?php

namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Observer; 

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface; 

protected $order;
protected $_productFactory;
public function __construct(
  \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order,
  \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
)
{
  $this->order = $order;
  $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/nitesh.log');
    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
    $logger->info($order->getOrderId());
    $product = $this->_productFactory->create();
    foreach($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item ) {
      $productColl = $product->load($item->getProductId());
      $logger->info($productColl->getData("Hana"));
    }
}
```

**Remove generation or generated folder and clean cache.**

Comment: not working get empty details $logger->info('hana===>'.$productColl->getData("Hana"));  2018-12-04T10:41:14+00:00 INFO (6): hana===>

Comment: I think Hana is not attribute_code it's attribute label. You need to add attribute_code in getData() function

Comment: how to set  attribute_code in getData() function  magento . Rohan Hapani

Comment: Go to admin -> store -> Attributes -> Product. Now, write Hana in Default Label and search. Then, get value of attribute_code column and add into getData()

Answer (score 0):

To get Order Item Qty

> Use below code

```
$item->getQtyOrdered();
```

> Instead of

```
$item->getQty();
```

Comment: want to print $logger->info( $item->getHana());  //" HANA is new attribute name in a variants product"